# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67

Tags: laravel-5

I know that this is a known error with things like forms in Laravel. But I am facing an issue with basic authentication in Laravel 5.2.

I created the auth using Laravel;

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Now I have the same copy of code on my server and my local. On my local I am getting no issue whatsoever. However on my server, when I try to register a user I get the error saying `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67`

Both my local and server environments are in sync, yet I keep getting the error on registration. Any help on how I can fix this?

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Try to run <code>php artisan key:generate</code> besides check the crsf field in the login, logout, create views: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: You can solve by hide or delete the line. go to app\http\kernal.php, here you can see the line `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`

Comment: Refer to section: **Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection**, in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Comment: I think it is write permission issue, try this command at your own risk, in project root folder: `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'm assuming you added `$this->middleware('auth');` inside the constructor of your controller to get the authentication working. In your login/register forms, if you are using `{!! Form::someElement !!}`, add the following line at the top as well:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Or if you are using input tags inside your forms, just add the following line after `<form>` tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Like I said I used php artisan make:auth. The boilerplate login and registration forms provided by Laravel have the {!! csrf_field() !!} by default added in them. Check other forms on my site and all have that csrf protection. Like I said its working in my local without issues but as soon as I check on server, its breaking.

Comment: Does Login work on your server, or nothing works regarding authentication? Also have you checked the configuration on both local and server environment? It should be same @GauravMehta

Comment: No login is also not working on server. What do you mean by checked configuration on both local and server? Are you referring to a specific file or some other configuration?

Comment: The version should be same and you should install all the modules on your server as well as you did on your local environment @GauravMehta

Comment: Yeah all that match since I did a composer update on both environments together.

Comment: If name is _token then how can we access the value? (particular input value from form), example, normally i can get like `$_POST['phone'];`

Comment: I have given this. But still the same error comes.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue and it was an easy fix.

Add this in your HTML meta tag area  :

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then under your JQuery reference, add this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
  </script>
```

If you are using the HTML form submit (not AJAX) then you need to put :

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

inside your form tags.

Comment: Where do I find the JQuery reference?

Comment: In your answer up above you say that under the JQuery reference, to add the code "<script type="text/javascript">.." , I'm wondering where exactly I need to add this code, where can I find the JQuery reference

Comment: jquery reference can be as following:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Under near that, add the code::
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
  </script>

Answer (score 11):

I was about to start pulling out my hair!

Please check your session cookie domain in session.php config. There is a domain option that has to match your environment and it's good practice to have this configurable with you .env file for development.

```
'domain' => env('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'some-sensible-default.com'),
```

Comment: This saved my morning. By default it is set to null, but I had a value to set this in my .env file I forgot about. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You need to have this line of code in the  section of your HTML document, you could do that by default , it won't do any harm:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And in your form you need to add this hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Thats it, worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

If nothing is working you can remove the CSRF security check by going to App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file and adding your routes to protected $excpt.

e.g. if i want to remove CSRF protection from all routes.

```
protected $except = [
    '/*'
];
```

P.S although its a good practice to include CSRF protection.

Comment: This is a bad idea and does not answer the post as well as making everyone believe this is a solution. Your solution is like saying "do not mind security measures, just ignore them" without saying anything about why it's a bad idea to disable csrf protection.

Comment: This makes the app vulnerable.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue with my application running on laravel 5.4

```
php artisan session:table
php artisan make:auth
php artisan migrate
```

.. and then following command works for me :)

```
chmod 777 storage/framework/sessions/
```

One more possibility of this issue, if you have set SESSION_DOMAIN (in .env) different than HOST_NAME

Happy coding

Comment: you are brilliant.

Comment: The solution in my case was to change `SESSION_DOMAIN` in the `.env` file from  `https://example.com` to `example.com`

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced the same issue and solved it later.
first of all execute the artisan command:

> php artisan cache:clear

And after that restart the project.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 5):

Your form method is post. So open the Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken .php file , find the isReading() method and  add 'POST' method in array.

Answer (score 5):

There are lot of possibilities that can cause this problem.
let me mention one. 
Have you by any chance altered your session.php config file?
May be you have changed the value of domain from null to you site name or anything else in session.php

`'domain' => null,`

Wrong configuration in this file can cause this problem.

Comment: This was the issue i had.

Answer (score 5):

By default session cookies will only be sent back to the server if the browser has a **HTTPS** connection. You can turn it off in your .env file (discouraged for production)

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
```

Or you can turn it off in config/session.php

```
'secure' => false,
```

Answer (score 3):

I also get this error, but I was solved the problem. If you using `php artisan serve` add this code `{{ csrf_field() }}` under `{!! Form::open() !!}`

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. Clear cache & cookies browser
3. Using Private Browser (Mozilla) / Incognito Window (Chrome)
4. Open your form/page and then submit again guys

I hope this is solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

is added within your form in blade syntax.

or in simple form syntax

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

along with this,
make sure, in session.php (in config folder), following is set correctly.

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'sample-project.com'),
```

or update the same in .env file like,

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=sample-project.com
```

In my case {!! csrf_field() !!} was added correctly but SESSION_DOMAIN was not configured correctly. After I changed it with correct value in my .env file, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

change the session driver in session.php to file mine was set to array.

Answer (score 2):

Can also occur if 'www-data' user has no access/write permissions 
on the folder:
'laravel-project-folder'/storage/framework/sessions/

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me.

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your hidden input field where the token is generated?

If it is null then your token is not returned by csrf_token function.You have to write your route that renders the form inside the middleware group provide by laravel as follows:

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Here root route contains my sign up page which requires csrf token. This token is managed by laravel 5.2.7 inside 'web' middleware in kernel.php.

Do not forget to insert {!! csrf_field() !!} inside the form..

Answer (score 1):

Go to `app/provides`.

Then, in file `RouteServiceProvider.php`, you'll have to delete `'middleware' => 'web'` in `protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)`

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in between `<form>` and  `</form>` tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem by me was to small post_max_size value in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I solved it by correcting my form open as shown below :

```
{!!Form::open(['url'=>route('auth.login-post'),'class'=>'form-horizontal'])!!}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, can you please show how you opened the form ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

Add **{{ csrf_field() }}** just after your form opening tag like so.

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/{{ $action_id }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting it back after the post ? I had this issue and I was able to solve it by returning the same view instead of using the Redirect::back().

Use this return view()->with(), instead of Redirect::back().

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use secure https rather than http.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the session lifetime on `config/session.php` like this :

`'lifetime' => 120,` to `'lifetime' => 360,`

Here I set lifetime to  360, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when uploading large files (videos). Form worked fine, no mismatch error, but as soon as someone attached a large video file it would throw this token error. Adjusting the maximum allowable file size and increasing the processing time solved this problem for me. Not sure why Laravel throws this error in this case, but here's one more potential solution for you.

Here's a StackOverflow answer that goes into more detail about how to go about solving the large file upload issue.

[PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a problem when trying to login after restarting server, but I had csrf field in the form and I didn't refresh the page, or it kept something wrong in the cache.

This was my solution. I put this piece of code in \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    try {
        return parent::handle($request, $next); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    } catch(TokenMismatchException $e) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

What it does is catching the TokenMismatchException and then redirecting the user back to the page (to reload csrf token in header and in the field). 
It might not work always, but it worked for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try php artisan cache:clear or manually delete storage cache from server.

Answer (score 0):

If you check some of the default forms from Laravel 5.4 you fill find how this is done:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required> @if ($errors->has('email'))
      <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span> @endif
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Send Password Reset Link
                                </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

is the most appropriate way to add a custom hidden field that Laravel will understand.

`csrf_filed()` uses `csrf_token()` inside as you can see:

```
if (! function_exists('csrf_field')) {
    /**
     * Generate a CSRF token form field.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
     */
    function csrf_field()
    {
        return new HtmlString('<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">');
    }
}
```

And `csrf_field()` method uses session for the job.

```
function csrf_token()
{
    $session = app('session');

    if (isset($session)) {
        return $session->token();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException('Application session store not set.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when I was trying out Laravel 5.2 at first, then I learnt about `{{!! csrf_field() !!}}` to be added in the form and that solved it. But later I learnt about Form Helpers, this takes care of CSRF protection and does not give any errors. Though Form Helpers are not legitimately available after Laravel 5.2, you can still use them from [LaravelCollective](http://LaravelCollective.com).

Answer (score 0):

Got to your laravel folder :: App/http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        // Pass your URI here. example ::

        '/employer/registration'
    ];
}
```

And it will exclude this url from the Csrf validation. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
output_buffering=4096;
always_populate_raw_post_data=-1;
upload_max_filesize=120M;
```

create user.ini file in public_html  and put above three values in user.ini file
solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?= csrf_token(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this exception and I solved it like this: Browse to your projects directory and open VerifyCsrfToken.php from app\Http\Middleware\ directory. And list the URIs (routes) that caused the exception in the provided array.

```
protected $except = [
   //list your routes here
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything(Clear cache, edit php ini, change config and .env file) but was unsuccessful. But when I ran this artisan command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

it worked.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

protected $except = ['api/*'];
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve by  delete the line. go to app\http\kernel.php, here you can see the line \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, This worked for me.

Comment: You don't want to do this. This will make you vulnerable for CSRF attacks. I **strongly** recommend not doing this!

Answer (score -3):

Please follow a very simple step. You just have to comment the following line of in the `app\http\kernel.php`  and not `app\kernel.php` file:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

I hope, it will solve your problem, and let me know if its not working.

Comment: you should never do that, as its for security which is provided by default.

Comment: I hope you don't know CSRF

Comment: It's there to protect your application from cross-site request forgery(CSRF) attacks. Never comment this line.