# Laravel 5.3 - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

Tags: laravel-5.3

When I log in to my app, and immediately go back when I enter it, and then try to log out, I get the error from the title, how can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67)

Answer (score 8):

I was facing same issue with laravel 5.4 .. and then following command works for me :)

chmod 777 storage/framework/sessions/

before this, it was chmod 775 storage/framework/sessions/ ... hence I was facing the issue...

Happy coding

Comment: Here on StackOverFlow we are tired of saying `chmod 777 is a bad idea`. You are giving permission to **ANYONE** write on that folder. What if someone gains access to that folder and uploads a script to list all users or drop a users table?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by editing the file **config->session.php**

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

and removing **SESSION_DOMAIN** from the file (.env)

and finally **composer dumpautoload**

Comment: There is no SESSION_DOMAIN property. Do you mean SESSION_DRIVER?

Comment: There is 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null), in session.php

Comment: This worked for me on Heroku... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From Laravel 5.3 docs

> The Auth::routes method now registers a POST route for /logout instead of a GET route. This prevents other web applications from logging your users out of your application. To upgrade, you should either convert your logout requests to use the POST verb or register your own GET route for the /logout URI:

**Option One:** 
`Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');`

For more about upgrade please have a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

**Option 2**

```
//Insert this on your head section
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

Where you want you logout

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li>
       <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> Logout
         </a>

        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
         </form>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Cheers

Comment: You state <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> I am unfamiliar - is this a shorthand for <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php csrf_token() ?>"

Comment: The scripts part messes up my whole syntax, is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @NicolasV what seems to be the issue?

Comment: @usrNotFound I use Atom and the colorscheme for my syntax goes crazy when I include this, makes me think there is something not closed off properly. But it runs, does not give an error.. ! See here: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/290zwy1/9

Comment: does you code works as suppose to? if it does do `window.Laravel = "<?php echo json_encode(['csrfToken'  =>  csrf_token(), ]); ?>"` i.e put them on a same line

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue because I set `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),` to `true` for my localhost. The value is in the `project-folder/config/session.php` file. Since my localhost wasn't `https` that's why I was facing the issue. After making it `false` for my localhost the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I have added `SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost` in my .env file when my `APP_URL` is `APP_URL=http://localhost`. It works for me I use `laravel` 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have the same issue in Laravel 5.4, when I upload a file using a form, I sent the token and the file uploads correctly. The issue appears when I upload a file that exceeds the max filesize upload. So, just add an exception in the VerifyCsrfToken.php for the route and the message disapears, but the file doesn't get upload.

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    protected $except = [

        'anexoSesion',
    ];
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I run Laravel / PHP on a Windows machine with `IIS`. If you do as well, please make sure, the user `IUSR` have modify rights on the project directories.
After permitting the user, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will generally occur due to permissions.  As Manish noted you can chmod 777 on your sessions folder, however, I would not recommend this ever.  First check if you have the same issue with the app using artisan serve (as opposed to serving your app via Nginx or Apache).  If you don't then it is a permissions issue and you can change the ownership of the folder accordingly.  Most likely it is the www-data user that needs permissions to write to the folder, however, you will want to check your environment to make sure as the user will differ in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this add those two lines in the route file (e.g web.php)

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');// so when you logged out it go back 
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

This solved the problem for me. Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

**Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php**

use Closure; // import

```
protected $except = [
    //
];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if (last(explode('\\',get_class($response))) != 'RedirectResponse') {
        $response->header('P3P', 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

**or**

---

**for all url**

```
protected $except = [
    '*'
];
```

**or**

---

**If there is no use**

**Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php**

// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class

this line add comment

Answer (score 0):

> Out of the box, Laravel comes with web and api middleware groups that contains common middleware you may want to apply to your web UI and API routes

If you check your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, you will find that by default, a `web` middleware group is applied to all your routes in `routes/web.php`.

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

Now, if you go check your `app/Http/Kernel.php` and take a look at the `$middlewareGroups` property, you will find a new `EncryptCookies` middleware. You can read about it, but if you remove this middleware from the `web` middleware group, your app might not give the `TokenMismatchException` which you are getting currently.

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing this problem when using laravel5.4 for rest API. Just add the route name to the app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file.

```
protected $except = [

    'test/login',
];
```

After adding the line, then I run the API, it executes successfully.

Comment: This is not a solution, because then the check won't be done anymore.

Answer (score -3):

I faced this kind of problem in  version 5.3.29
The following method worked for me.

Just change the following line in your .env file.

```
APP_KEY=base64:aBCdeFghI+jKLMnOPqRSTuvw1xYzAbCDeFgHiJKL57+4= (example key)
```

remove the **base64:** part, and make it like following

```
APP_KEY=aBCdeFghI+jKLMnOPqRSTuvw1xYzAbCDeFgHiJKL57+4=
```

Answer (score -4):

go to **middleware** -> **verifycsrftoken.php** -> add the urls in the array specified.