# "The page has expired due to inactivity" - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-5.5

My register page is showing the form properly with CsrfToken (`{{ csrf_field() }}`) present in the form).

**Form HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal registration-form" novalidate method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        ....
</form>
```

I am using inbuilt authentication for the users. Have not changed anything except the routes and redirects.

When I submit the form (just after reloading also), it gives that **The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.** error.

My be I am missing a very small thing. But not sure what it is. Any help?

**Update**

Found the issue. The session driver was set to array. Changed it to file and the error is gone now.
But what is wrong if I use array?

Comment: May have something to do with the storage_path not being writable.  This is where it stores session data regarding tokens if you're using file based sessions.

Comment: Found the issue. The session driver was set to `array`. Changed it to file and the error is gone now. But what is wrong if I use array?

Comment: or this url check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997180/laravel-5-3-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-68/45354029#45354029

Comment: For new version of laravel, use @csrf to solve problem.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**If you're coming to this answer directly from a search**, make sure you have already added the csrf token to your form with `{{ csrf_field() }}` like the OP.

---

**If you have your session driver set to file:**

May have something to do with the storage_path not being writable. This is where it stores session data regarding tokens if you're using file based sessions.  The can be verified with `is_writable(config('session.files'))`

---

**For the OP, the session driver was set to array.**  Array is for testing only.  Since data is not persisted, it will not be able to compare the token on the next request.

> The array driver is used during testing and prevents the data stored
>   in the session from being persisted.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#configuration

---

**Check config/session.php**

Lastly, an issue I just had, we had a project which has the session domain and secure settings in config/session.php but the development site was not using HTTPS (SSL/TLS).  This caused this generic error since sessions.secure was set to true by default.

Comment: Ok. But for now it is in development. So if I use array, why it was giving me that error?

Comment: @SougataBose testing is not development.  Array data is not persisted...

Comment: That's the reason one should go through the DOCs properly.. :)

Comment: My problem was not solved. I did the basics truly. But I'm using custom providers and services. There is no problem when I call a controller method but when I run a service method in a controller that called with post request, the problem appears!

Comment: I had a similar issue with sessions but in regards to testing. Turned out when I was using `Carbon::setTestNow($time);` in the tests I was not clearing it by using `Carbon::setTestNow();` afterwards.

Answer (score 81):

I ran into the same issue in Laravel 5.5. In my case, it happened after changing a route from GET to POST. The issue was because I forgot to pass a CSRF token when I switched to POST.

You can either post a CSRF token in your form by calling:

```
 {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or exclude your route in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
 protected $except = [
        'your/route'
    ];
```

Comment: `csrf_field()` present in the form. The accepted answer describes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I was receiving a POST from a 3rd party, so adding the csrf_field() was not an option. Since CSRF was not a factor in my case, adding an exception to this route solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: My problem was not solved. I did the basics truly. But I'm using custom providers and services. There is no problem when I call a controller method but when I run a service method in a controller that called with post request, the problem appears!

Comment: Please do not disable CSRF verification!  It's very important to protection to have.  Learn how to properly send the token and protect your logged in users from malicious javascript that can submit actions on their behalf.

Answer (score 12):

Try all of them.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Instead of try all above commands, use this package https://github.com/afrazahmmad/clear-all-cached-data

Answer (score 8):

This caused because of `Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException`
look at this code sample how to handle it properly:

> https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/bd0f9ad0ef1ed6bb594e

Answer (score 7):

My case was solved with `SESSION_DOMAIN`, in my local machine had to be set to `xxx.localhost`. It was causing conflicts with the production `SESSION_DOMAIN`, `xxx.com` that was set directly in the session.php config file.

Comment: Which session driver you were using? `file` or `cookie`?

Answer (score 4):

Some information is stored in the cookie which is related to previous versions of laravel in development. So it's conflicting with csrf generated tokens which are generated by another's versions. Just  Clear the cookie and give a try.

Comment: did you able to see `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Umr1AlG3sScdUWGtMoHcQPPKASsR7qsd5ZE1H3Xv">` kind of code in generated html ?

Comment: It is there. Found the issue. The session driver was set to array. Changed it to file and the error is gone now.

Answer (score 4):

I change permission to storage and error was gone. It seemed lack of permission was the issue.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage/
```

Comment: Be careful using such open permissions recursively.  I'd highly recommend against 775 for files.  755 for directories and 644 for files is the norm.

Answer (score 4):

For those who still has problem and nothing helped. Pay attention on php.ini mbstring.func_overload parameter. It has to be set to 0. And mbstring.internal_encoding set to UTF-8. In my case that was a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer saved my brain from crashing)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the site was fine in server but not in local. Then I remember I was working on secure website.
So in file config.session.php, set the variable secure to false

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

Answer (score 3):

add `@csrf` in the form
and also go to VerifyCsrfToken.php

app->Http->Middleware->VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
        'paste your route here'
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out two solution to avoid these error
1)by adding protected $except = ['/yourroute'] possible disable csrf token inspection from defined root.
2)just comment  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class line in protected middleware group in kernel

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Add the route entry for `register` in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected $except = [
        '/routeTo/register'
    ];
```

and clear the cache and the cache route with the commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear
```

**Details**

Every time you access a Laravel site, a token is generated, even if the session has not been started. Then, in each request, this token (stored in the cookies) will be validated against its expiration time, set in the `SESSION_LIFETIME` field on `config/session.php` file.

If you keep the site open for more than the expiration time and try to make a request, this token will be evaluated and the expiration error will return. So, to skip this validation on forms that are outside the functions of authenticated users (such as register or login) you can add the except route in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.

Comment: If that page processes user input then it should go through **CSRF** checks.

Comment: @SougataBose Indeed, in that case I think it is best to use a captcha validator as Google reCAPTCHA

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have the correct system time on your web server.  In my case, the vagrant machine was in the future (Jan 26 14:08:26 UTC 2226) so of course the time in my browser's session cookie had expired some 200+ years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had the app with multiple subdomains and session cookie was the problem between those. Clearing the cookies resolved my problem.

Also, try setting the `SESSION_DOMAIN` in **.env** file. Use the exact subdomain you are browsing.

Answer (score 0):

set **mbstring.func_overload = 2**

it helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the problem is not in the framework but in the browser. I don't know why but google chrome blocks cookies automatically, in my case. After allowed cookies the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Many time its happening because you are testing project in back date

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

use incognito new tab then test it again.

reason:

in my case another user logged in with my admin panel

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on Linux-mint but then realized that the htdocs folder had no full permissions. So I changed the permissions of all the subdirectories in the htdocs folder by doing: `sudo chown -c -R $USER:$USER /opt/lampp/htdocs/*`

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to connect to the server.

Search Error

An error has occurred: search false You don't have the peais.

Search request is longer.

Comment: Please be more specific in the steps OP needs to take.