# The page has expired due to inactivity - in Production

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, load-balancing

I have no problems of this sort during development but after pushing to production, keep getting the error message "The page has expired due to inactivity".

I tried clearing cache and all that...

**composer dump-autoload && php artisan optimize && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear**

But it doesn't seem to help

The quick fix right now is turn off one of the application servers, but both of them running causes the page expired error. And as previously noted, this only happens in production after every push

Comment: `APP_DEBUG=true`  set this in your .env and check

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The page has expired due to inactivity" - Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5)

Comment: I just did and it is still showing the same error. But I would like to add that this usually happens after I do a git push to production.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the application key set in the .env file?

Try running `php artisan key:generate`

Also: Do you have some sort of error log from the server itself? Maybe you get more info from that.

Answer (score 0):

I also have got the **Page Expired** error in Laravel.

If you get a page expired ( 419 ) issue means an issue with your **CSRF token**.

**Solution 1**

> If you are getting an error after submitting the form then you need to
> add the CSRF field to your form request.

**Solution 2**

> If you are getting an error after calling the AJAX then you need to
> add a header for CSRF token using the example below.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
```

**Solution 3 : disable csrf protection ( Not Recommended )**

*Note: disable CSRF protection use only for webhooks*

```
disable CSRF protection field for routes group or specific routes

open file VerifyCsrfToken.php on your project

dir - App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

**Example Below**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
    'payment/*', // routes group
    'specific-route', // specific route
    '*', // allow all request 
   ];
}
```