# page expired exception in laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, csrf

This is often seen in Laravel. When a form is submitted, sometimes the application redirects to a page saying:

> The page has expired due to inactivity.
>
> Please refresh and try again.

I know that this is a security mechanism in Laravel against CSRF. How can it be prevented from displaying since this may not be appropriate when application is deployed in production server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The page has expired due to inactivity" - Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5)

Comment: In your middleware folder, there is a file named `VerifyCsrfTocken.php`. There you just need to add to the array `$except` the routes you dont want to be secured with a csrf token

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the `419.blade.php` template that is being resolved.

If you want to change the message, you can make this file in `views/errors/419.blade.php`

If you want to capture the exception and perform your own actions against it, you can use the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` and specifically capture `$e instanceof TokenMismatchException`.

Then within that conditional you can choose what action to take.