# “The page has expired due to inactivity” - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, session, caching

I'm using Laravel Collective Form and running Laravel 5.6. There is no error in local MAMP. However, after I setup in Production (Ubuntu) on AWS, the form was not working. When I submitted the form, it always went to "The page has expired due to inactivity".

Before I asked, I've already tried the other suggested methods, but still didn't work.

**Clear Cache**

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan route:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

**Set Directory Permissions**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

**Session Cookie Domain**

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

**Session Secure Value**

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

What else am I missing?

Update: looks like it's a CSRF token mismatch issue.

Comment: did you tried `php artisan key:generate` ?

Comment: Are you getting this error after submitting form ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The page has expired due to inactivity" - Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5)

Comment: Yes, the key is already generated. @Goms

Comment: @C2486 I am getting the error after submitting form.

Comment: Use `csrf_field` as in given link

Comment: Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the csrf_field helper to generate the token field:

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya the CSRF token filed is already included in the form.

Comment: try it - exclude your route in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php  
  protected $except = [
        'your/route'
    ];

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya it works while excluding the token, but if I exclude the token, the form validation is not working. Is there any way to resolve the token issue?

Comment: @trojan For more details:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Answer (score 0):

Inside the route file, add the followings:

```
Route::get('csrf', function() {
    return Session::token();
});
```

---

Someone told me that this is the issue with current session token and provide the above solution. But, I am not sure why the session token is different from the CSRF token on the form.