# The page has expired due to inactivity.Please refresh and try again in Login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a problem with the login when I try to log in it says the page has expired due to inactivity.I am using middleware to check role based on user login and it seems it's not working. When ever try to login the page has expired message popups.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('/dashboard/{user_id}', ['as' => 'dashboard', function ($user_id) {
    return view('theme.index')->with(['id'=>$user_id]);
}]);
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postSignIn')->name('login');
```

**AuthController:**

```
 public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            $user=DB::table('users')->where([['username', '=', $request['username']],['status','=','0']])->first();
            $user_id=$user->user_id;


            return redirect()->route('dashboard',$user_id)->with('message', 'State saved correctly!!!');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

**Middleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() === null) {
            //  return response("Insufficient permissions", 401);
            return response(view('error'),401);
        }
        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;

        if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles) {
            return $next($request);
        }
//        return response("Insufficient permissions", 401);
        return response(view('error'),401);
    }

}
```

**Index:**

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
   {{ csrf_token() }}
   <div class="form-group m-b-20 row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <label for="emailaddress">Username</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" required="" placeholder="Enter Username">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row m-b-20">
      <div class="col-12">
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row text-center m-t-10">
      <div class="col-12">
         <button class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache. or Try running your app in the incog mode to check if its a problem with the cache.

Comment: i did it but it's same @Saurabh

Comment: this happened to me and i think i solve it by adding crf token in the view

Comment: @Hussein, the OP has already added `{{ csrf_token() }}`

Comment: @Abhijith, please check your session config file under `config/session.php` check if all the configuration are correct and make sure your browser is not blocking any cookies.

Comment: Let me check that @Saurabh

Comment: Also, do an Inspect Element to the form on the browser to check whether or not you are getting a valid CSRF Token filed.

Comment: i getting a csrf tokken and session configration is correct @Saurabh

Comment: what is the reason i can't figure it out

Comment: this error can happen also if you have different error like 403, try to log the values of variables and see if they are all correct

Comment: I have gone through the logs nothing i could find... @Hussein

Comment: @Abhijith Similar question was asked here. This page can help you to find the solution of your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Let me check that @aishazafar

Comment: @Abhijith does it work for you?

Comment: no it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured it out i did it from scratch it was the problem of Auth function
The import Auth before that i did run two commands to clear my cache

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache


and import Auth
```

Thank you for the help guys appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

You can change the session lifetime in Laravel config inside config/session.php by modifying following value

> lifetime

also you will need to run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

for Laravel to pick new configurations.

Comment: 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false, in this where should i use it @Aman

Comment: @Abhijith First of all it's not CSRF failure but rather specific to session. And second yes, that should pretty much resolve your issue :)

Comment: `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),` is getting overridden by `SESSION_LIFETIME=20` in `.env` so change that or just `lifetime = 360`.

Answer (score 0):

add your route in $except array of VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware like this  $except = [ "/login" ]; .

Comment: is it like this protected $except = [

        Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postSignIn')->name('login');
    ];

Comment: if it is like this,it's says expression is not allowed deafault value @Amol Rokoade

Comment: U can do like this  $except = [ "/login" ];

Answer (score 0):

open VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware and put in except your url like :

```
protected $except = [
'http://localhost:8000/login'
```

];

and can see laravel docs for more information about csrf
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris