# Laravel forcing POST routes into GET

Tags: laravel, post, get, routes, laravel-5.4

Router:

```
Route::post('/submit/{id}', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit/{{$id}}">
```

The above changes the URL to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit/$id` and returns

> Page has Expired Due to Inactivity.

It looks like Laravel is trying to force the POST into a GET.

Comment: this answer for `Page has expired`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141940/9613505

Comment: I think you are using get type route in your POST request. Check this [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: @Hussein, Thanks, worked

Comment: @seamus i think the `$id` in html is not parsed, are you sure that html name is something like: `example.blade.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because you forget to put the CSRF token field into the form.

Try with:

**Option 1**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('submit', [$id])}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Option 2**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('submit')}}/{{$id}}">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

For more info see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)