# Laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity token is present

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I just deployed my laravel app on shared hosting with php 7.2.
App is working fine on DigitalOcean and on my local Homestead.

But when hosting on shared hosting with php7.2

```
/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.2.5 (cli) (built: May  2 2018 05:43:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
with Zend OPcache v7.2.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Every form has token as you can see below

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="yuRpoUdnDHdXqwS0n6hzTfprXXXXXZR8fg9IP">
```

But still getting:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 
Please refresh and try again.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The page has expired due to inactivity" - Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5)

Comment: no it is not, I do have {{ csrf_field() }} in my all of the forms, but still getting this error message.

Comment: Make sure that the storage folder is writable by the web server - otherwise sessions are not created.

Comment: Thank @Snapey it was permissions on storage folder were missing.

Comment: The page has expired due to inactivity. 
Please refresh and try again.

appear again, I made sure that storage has correct rights. then I move session to database still same problem.