# Laravel 5.6 The page has expired due to inactivity token is present

Tags: laravel-5

Same question already has been ask here, and I have tried everything read.

My old question reference
[Laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity token is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593542/laravel-5-5-the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-token-is-present)

I have tried:
["The page has expired due to inactivity" - Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5)
https://www.5balloons.info/fixed-page-expired-due-inactivity-laravel-5/

I have tried file and database both for cache and session, all of my forms has TOKEN.

Permissions on storage

```
 drwxrwxrwx  5 ABC ABC   4096 May 30 23:16 storage
```

My .env file

```
APP_NAME="Name"
APP_ENV=staging
APP_KEY=SOMEKEY
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=false
APP_URL=http://url

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql.host.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=db_user_password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="email" class="control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

What am I missing here, no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do these :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

And in controller constructor try to flush the session because this csrf_token is stored in the session per user.

```
public function __construct()
{
    Session::flush();
}

Session::regenerateToken(); // Which generates a new token on request.
```

And you can try this also :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
```

Comment: I forgot to run php artisan config:cache, and it solved the issue.
Thanks