# laravel 5.6 random error "The page has expired due to inactivity"

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.6

My Laravel 5.6 project was working well.

But suddenly when I try to login sometimes it says

> The page has expired due to inactivity.

and sometimes it login properly with out any error. For example

- I go to page 127.0.0.1:8000/login...submit login form and get that error.
- I refresh the 127.0.0.1:8000/login page...submit...again error.
- I refresh the 127.0.0.1:8000/login page...submit and it works properly :|

Anybody know whats wrong with my project?!

this project works on my host without any problem and I have `{{ csrf_field }}` in my form.

I've tried to clear cache, view, route, config and deleting browser cache/cookie 
and change SESSION_DRIVER=array but still got error.

UPDATE :
another thing that i should say is when it work properly and i login to the panel...when i submit any forms i got out of the panel and i should login again.

Comment: Read this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141705/the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-laravel-5-5?rq=1

Comment: thank you but i set session_driver=array and still got error sometimes

Comment: try this command in console 

sudo chmod -R 777 storage/  bootstrap/
and let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: i change these two folders permissions manualy to 777...not work

Comment: try this: php artisan serve --host=127.1.1.1 --port=8888. 
if it works then there is issue with cache of the project

Comment: i update the issue

Comment: i run project on 127.1.1.1:8888...still have the same problem...:(

Comment: did you update your laravel version ?

Comment: Try this also: in config/session.php
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'http://localhost'),

Comment: my laravel version is 5.6 from begin.
i try changing session_domain but still have problem.

Answer (score 0):

for localhost development open `kernel.php` inside `Http` folder and just comment this line :

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

the csrf protection of laravel doesn't work properly on `localhost`. I already tried everything. just comment that, it's very annoying problem.

Comment: i do this but now when i click on login button it do some process and just refresh the login page and nothing happen.

Comment: that's another question. I didn't use laravel's auth system. I should not recommend anything about that. but try to clear all cache and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

finaly...after 3 bad days focus on this issue...i find the answer and i hope it help someone else :

> check your browser setting -> cookies and see how many cookies create
>   when a user login.

by default laravel create 2 cookies when user login with names :

1. "XSRF-TOKEN"
2. "laravel_session"

these are ok but other cookies which you create manually or other installed packages creates cause this problem.

i was using eloquent-viewable package and it creates a cookie everytime i logged in.

i remove this package and then everything works properly :)