# 419|PAGE EXPIRED in production, CSRF problem with Laravel 9 and Inertia?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, csrf, inertiajs

After deployment, when I try to use a `delete route`, this error is thrown:

```
419 | PAGE EXPIRED
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 ()
```

Function inside vue component from where the route is triggered:

```
const destroyEvent = (record) => {
    if (confirm('Delete event?')) {
        Inertia.delete(route('admin.event.destroy', {
            id: record.id,
            title: record.title,
            image_path: record.image_path,
        }), { preserveScroll: true })
    }
}
```

Web route:

```
Route::delete('/admin/event/destroy', [EventsController::class, 'destroyEvent'])->name('admin.event.destroy');
```

The Request does not seem to reach `EventsController`, which I've tested with `dd()`.

According to [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282822/laravel-419-page-expired-on-production-server-framework-laravel-version), it might be an `CSRF` token problem. I've tried everything proposed in there but it didn't help. Though commenting out:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

from `app\Kernel.php` removes the `419 | PAGE EXPIRED` screen and instead shows a blank page. Is this an indication of a `CSRF` problem?

From this [laracasts question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/nova/frustrating-419-page-expired-on-login-using-jetstream), I've also tried adding:

```
public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->environment('production') || $this->app->environment('staging'))
        {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

to `AppServiceProvider.php` with no improvement of the problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by using `form.delete` instead of `Inertia.delete`:

```
const destroyEvent = (record) => {
    if (confirm('Delete Event?')) {
        const form = useForm({
            id: record.id,
            title: record.title,
            image_path: record.image_path
        })
        form.delete(route('admin.event.destroy'), { preserveScroll: true })
    }
}
```

It would be useful to know how the `form` helper handles `CSRF` different from `Inertia`.