# Form data is not submitting into database using laravel 5.4 version

Tags: php, html, forms, token, laravel-5.4

I am trying to simply adding my form data but i dont know where i am wrong my html view:

```
<form action="{{url('add/talent')}}" method="post" role="form">

    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Middle Name</label>
                <input type="text"name="middle_name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text"name="last_name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email_address" id="input" class="form-control" value="" required="required" pattern="" title="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Profile Summary</label>
        <textarea name="" id="input" name="profile_summary" class="form-control" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>

    <p class="bold m-b-10">Open for following type</p>

    <div class="check-box-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Freelance Project
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> Contract Project
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> Part Time Hire
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> Direct Hire ( Full time )
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> SOW
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="m-t-20 m-b-20">
        <a href="add-talent-2" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Continue</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

My controller:

```
public function addTalent(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'first_name'         => 'required',
        'middle_name'        => 'required',
        'last_name'          => 'required',
        'email_address'      => 'required',
        'profile_summary'    => 'required',
    );
    $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('add-talent-1')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        // store
        $talent = new Talent();
        $talent->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
        $talent->middle_name = Input::get('middle_name');
        $talent->last_name = Input::get('last_name');
        $talent->email_address = Input::get('email_address');
        $talent->profile_summary = Input::get('profile_summary');
        $talent->save();
    }
}
```

and my model:

class Talent extends Model
   {
       protected $table = 'add_talent_1';

```
   protected $fillable = ['first_name','middle_name','last_name','email_address','profile_summary'];
```

}
and my routes/web.php

```
     Route::post('add/talent', 'AddTalent@addTalent');
```

if i test my route under routes/api.php usig postman and hit my post request it successfully add data into database using url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add/talent

but if i removed api and simply hit request using url http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/talent it says  TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
i dont know where i am doing my wrong why my form is not submitting my data

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You have a typo on `return Reddirect::to('add-talent-1')`.

Comment: Did you try answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997180/laravel-5-3-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-68 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel uses the csrf middleware in web routes to check and verify whether the request has a valid csrf token. This is not applicable in api routes, so it will work in your case when you send the request with postman. But you cannot do the same for a route defined in web.php.

Laravel offers a solution for this in their documentation though. You can add an exception for this route in csrf middleware.

> However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the
>   $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

You can find this middleware in:

> app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'add/talent',
    ];
}
```

Once you add the exception, you should be able to send the request using postman! Generally, it's recommended to put such routes in api.php, not in web.php. Csrf validation is a security feature given by Laravel and you shouldn't be excluding it unless you have a good reason to do so :)

Hope it helps. Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: I think this method is vulnerable to CSRF attack.

Comment: @Miron indeed it is. That's what I have mentioned in the answer.