# Laravel artisan serve on remote server

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Hi I have deployed my Laravel app on a remote server using `sudo php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80` but when I login I get TokenMismatchException. The app is working fine in my local environment and my login form did contains `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use `php artisan serve` command in the production mode. You have to just point out the baseUrl like `http://or.net/` to laravel's public/index.php file. It will bootstrap your laravel application with all the dependencies. For more details on the hosting of laravel on shared server, visit [this CW answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868393/laravel-shared-hosting-routes-not-working-properly/46409411#46409411).

And the solution to the CSRF token problem is answered by @sujalPatel. You have to add

`{!! csrf_field() !!}` not `{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: No offense but I did mention my form contains {{ csrf_field() }} and its working on local dev environment. It just stops working on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I'm assuming you added $this->middleware('auth'); inside the constructor of your controller to get the authentication working. Add the following at the top as well, under your login/register forms, if you are using {!! Form::someElement !!}:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Or if you are using input tags inside your forms, just add this just after the  tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

[TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67)

Comment: No offense but I did mention my form contains {{ csrf_field() }} and its working on local dev environment. It just stops working on remote server.