# Laravel | Shared hosting routes not working properly

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to deploy my Laravel project on a shared host(godaddy) and so far I have only partially succeeded.

**Steps I followed:**

- Create a subdomain `abc.xyz.com` , root -> `public_html/finance/.`
- Upload my laravel project to a folder which is at same level as that of `public_html`
- `softlink` the `public` directory of my project to `public_html/finance/`
- I found that going to `abc.xyz.com` didn't work but `abc.xyz.com/public` did so I set up a redirect which redirects `abc.xyz.com` to `abc.xyz.com`
- making `Storage` accessible for web.
- `dumpautoload`, caching `config` and `routes`.
- migarting `databases`.

Now I can successfully login which takes me to `abc.xyz.com/public` but my all other routes which does not have `/public` do not work.
For example:

- abc.xyz.com/public - works
- abc.xyz.com/home - doesn't work

I noticed that if I manually add `/public` to all routes they work!. so `abc.xyz.com/public/home` works.

**my .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**So how can append `/public` like `abc.xyz.com/public` to all the routes?**
I am not very good at modifying `.htaccess` but I tried some solutions from online and they did not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Excerpted from [Deploy Laravel 5 App on Shared Hosting on Linux Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816200145/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2410/deploy-laravel-5-app-on-shared-hosting-on-linux-server#t=201708162001451393879). The original authors were [Donkarnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220364/donkarnash), [PassionInfinite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4919058/passioninfinite), [Pete Houston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/801396/pete-houston) and [Kyslik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564365/kyslik). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/2410). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 2410.

By default Laravel project's `public` folder exposes the content of the app which can be requested from anywhere by anyone, the rest of the app code is invisible or inaccessible to anyone without proper permissions.

After developing the application on your development machine, it needs to be pushed to a production server so that it can be accessed through the internet from anywhere - right?

For most apps/websites the first choice is to use shared hosting package from hosting service providers like GoDaddy, HostGator etc. mainly due to low cost.

> **note**: you may ask your provider to manually change **document_root**, so all you have to do is upload your Laravel application to server (via FTP), request change of root to **{app}/public** and you should be good.

Such shared hosting packages, however do have limitations in terms of terminal access and file permissions. By default one has to upload their app/code to the `public_html` folder on their shared hosting account.

So if you want to upload a Laravel project to a shared hosting account how would you go about it? Should you upload the entire app (folder) to the `public_html` folder on your shared hosting account? - **Certainly NO**

Because everything in the `public_html` folder is accessible "publically i.e. by anyone" which would be a big security risk.

Steps to upload a project to shared hosting account - the Laravel way

**Step 1**
Create a folder called laravel (or anything you like) on the same level as the `public_html` folder.

```
Eg:  
/
|--var  
    |---www
        |----laravel       //create this folder in your shared hosting account
        |----public_html  
        |----log
```

**Step 2**
 Copy every thing except the `public` folder from your laravel project (on development machine) in the `laravel` folder (on server host - shared hosting account).
You can use:
 - C-panel : which would be the slowest option
 - FTP Client: like ***FileZilla*** to connect to you shared hosting account and transfer your files and folders through FTP upload
 - Map Network Drive: you can also create a mapped network drive on your development machine to connect to your shared hosting account's root folder using "ftp://your-domain-name" as the network address.

**Step 3**
 Open the `public` folder of your laravel project (on development machine), copy everything and paste in the `public_html` folder (on server host - shared hosting account).
**Step 4**
Now open the `index.php` file in the `public_html` folder on the shared hosting account (in cpanel editor or any other connected editor) and:

***Change:***

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

***To:***

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

***And Change:***

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

***To:***

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

***Save and close.***

**Step 5**
 Now go to the `laravel` folder (on shared hosting account -server) and open `server.php` file
***Change***

```
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

***To:***

```
require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/index.php';
```

***Save and close.***

**Step 6**
Set file permissions for the `laravel/storage` folder (recursively) and all files, sub-folders and file within them on shared hosting account - server to `777`.
***Note:*** Be careful with the file permissions in linux, they are like double edged sword, if not used correctly, they may make your app vulnerable to attacks. For understanding Linux file permissions you can read https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

**Step 7**

As `.env` file of local/development server is Ignored by git and it should be ignored as it has all the environment variables including the APP_KEY and it should not be exposed to public by pushing it into the repositories'. You can also see that `.gitignore` file has `.env` mentioned thus it will not upload it to repositories.

After following all the above steps make a `.env` file in the laravel folder and add all the environment variable which you have used from the local/development server's `.env` file to the `.env` file of production server.

Even there are configuration files like `app.php`, `database.php` in config folder of laravel application which defines this variables as by default in second parameter of `env()` but don't hard-code the values in these files as it will affect the configuration files of the users who pulls your repository. So it is recommended to create `.env` file manually!

Also laravel gives `.env-example` file that you can use as a reference.

That's it.

Now when you visit the url which you configured as the domain with your server, your laravel app should work just as it worked on your localhost - development machine, while still the application code is safe and not accessible by anyone without proper file permissions.

Comment: what will be the .htaccess code. can you please share it.

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: Please ask a separate question detailing why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Works perfect with Laravel 8 projects aswell. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably move your public/.htaccess and public/index.php to the root files of your laravel project.

Comment: Many Thanks. From all the tutorials on the web, your solution is the only one that works effectively.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the document root for you website to be the public folder of your application i.e.

```
public_html/finance/.
```

should be:

```
public_html/finance/public
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have placed the entire project in the public directory - public_html, haven't you? This is a bad practice (security).

Your domain (abc.xyz.com) points to your application root directory, should go to the app/public dir.

Comment: If you carefully read the steps I followed you will know that I didn't

Answer (score 0):

Update Solution:  require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
    Is now: require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
So **Change To** `require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pointing to the correct files and folders, add the below .htaccess file. Credit - [Kylevorster](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-requested-url-login-was-not-found-on-this-server?reply=303110)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```