# How to deploy laravel vue site to shared hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, deployment, eloquent

Deploy laravel vue app in shared hosting

I coppied *index.js* from public folder to root and changed autoload and bootstrap path.

public folder contains-

```
dist/css/app.css
dist/js/app.js
mix-manifest.json
```

mix-manifest.json

```
{
    "/dist/js/app.js": "/dist/js/app.js",
    "/dist/css/app.css": "/dist/css/app.css"
}
```

when i browse, 
http://domain_name/dist/css/app.css not found error

I deleted public folder and coppied everything to root.
But i m getting The Mix manifest does not exist error

Is there a way to overcome this.?

Deploying laravel vue app is a headache?
Can i use RewriteBase in htaccess to resolve issue

I can deploy laravel to shared hosting. but using vue in frontend seems not working as expected. I used vue-routes in frontend for routing rather than laravel routes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I'm doing it this way

- `npm run prod` to compile assets for production
- create a folder in the root directory in the shared host and copy all project files to it
- move project's public folder contents to public_html folder
- Edit index.php file and change autoload and bootstrap paths to point project folder
- Create a symlink to the image folder
  ex

> symlink('home/username/project_name/public/img','home/username/public_html/img');

- create a database and username in CPanel and add to .env file
- import data to database.

Comment: I followed exactly same method. but when i use vue js in frontend this method doesn't work with routes specified in vue

Comment: Ok i willl update the question. but its working perfectly in local computer with php artisan serve. When i move all contents of public folder to root and edit index.php, it throws mix-manifest not found error. I think their is no issue in route file and i followed the offcial doc as well

Comment: this will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153738/the-mix-manifest-does-not-exist-when-it-does-exist

Comment: ok thanks. but in my case the mix mainfest is in public_html folder and not inside public folder. so in this case the accepted answer is not the solution