# The Mix manifest does not exist laravel vuejs error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

[image]

I have installed my laravel-vue application on a cpanel-serve.
but every time I change something and upload `app.js` on server the browser cache history and I should use
`Ctrl+F5` or `Ctrl+R` to clear history.

I saw some solutions to user laravel mix and import like this

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

but when I upload it on serve I saw the error

> "The Mix manifest does not exist"

Is there any one help me?

Comment: Have tried one of the workaround [The Mix manifest does not exist when it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153738/the-mix-manifest-does-not-exist-when-it-does-exist)

Comment: I think this is your solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153738/the-mix-manifest-does-not-exist-when-it-does-exist

Comment: now the problem is with using mix.when I use mix I see the error in picture

Comment: I tried it like this even {{ mix('js/app.js', 'app') }} and my manifest is in public but the error did not change

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you haven't compiled your `js` and `css` assets.

If you are working on a dev environment, try running one of the following

```
npm run dev
npm run watch
npm run prod
```

I've encountered this when switching between production branches (where i have commited production assets) and development branches (where they are ignored by git)

Answer (score 0):

For me it shows a hint about the solution :

[Error's screenshot with a hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Tcw.png)

You missed `npm install && npm run dev`