# Laravel 8 The Mix manifest does not exist

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project where I'm using Jetstream. It works fine in localhost, but in webhost when I go to /dashboard I get following errors:

The Mix manifest does not exist. (/htdocs/laravelblog/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php)
Missing Mix Manifest File
Illuminate\Foundation\Mix::__invoke
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Mix.php:46

My mix-manifest.json file is located in my main directory - htdocs/mix-manifest.json

**mix-manifest.json**

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/main.css": "/css/main.css",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

Comment: This answer might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47518119/1379025