# Problems in Laravel when logging in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am uploading my first Laravel application to a hosting, and after creating a user, I get the following error:

[screenshot from error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exD89.png)

I am seeing that the registration of the new user was created successfully
[scheenshot pryect in host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AypWQ.png)

My project is in the dash_roles test folder, while everything that was in public, I put in the public_html folder.

I clarify that the project is with Laravel 9, I already verified that the same version of PHP with which I made the project is selected on my server. Modify the lines in the index.php file located in public_html.

If you need me to upload something else so you can find where the error is, let me know and I'll upload it.

Thanks!

edit: here a screenshot for my assets un app.blade.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HihZ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153738/the-mix-manifest-does-not-exist-when-it-does-exist

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you compile your assets?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612)

Answer (score 0):

Can you further provide the steps which you did from starting, also did you compile the assets before running the code?
if not first check with following steps in your terminal.

1. first run these code to check if node or npm is running or not.
   `node -v` and `npm -v`
   if not installed, then install it `npm install`, after that
2. Run all Mix tasks and minify output...
   `npm run prod`
3. try this

`mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');`

Comment: I copy what the console throws me in my local project:

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\dash_roles - test> node -v
v16.13.2
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\dash_roles - test> npm -v
8.1.2

Comment: Is there a way to execute these codes in a console from the project uploaded to the host? because I only run them from my visual studio editor in the local project

on the other hand, I didn't compile assets before executing the code, nor did I know that it had to be done; Is there any guide to help me do this? I would be very grateful

Comment: request you to be more specific or if ou found the solution then post it too for others to get insight by it and if not then relate the issues