# Laravel routes in Shared Hosting not works properly

Tags: php, laravel, routes, shared-hosting

I'm with a problem very similar with [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868393/laravel-shared-hosting-routes-not-working-properly), but the solutions provided in that thread not helped me.

I made the deploy of my Laravel app to a shared hosting service using this [guide](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) (BTW, the guide is very similar to [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409411/3943162) of the linked question)

Below is my routes/web.php file

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'law', 'middleware' => ['ability:superadministrator,read-users|create-users']], function () {

    Route::get('/search', 'LawController@showSearchView');
    Route::get('/new', ['middleware' => ['permission:create-users'], 'uses' => 'LawController@showNewView']);

    Route::get('/find', 'LawController@find');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'LawController@edit');

    //region post
    Route::post('/new', ['middleware' => ['permission:create-users'], 'uses' => 'LawController@store']);
    Route::post('/search', ['middleware' => ['permission:read-users'], 'uses' => 'LawController@search']);
    /*Route::post('/modify', ['middleware' => ['permission:create-users'], 'uses' => 'LawController@modify']);*/
    //endregion
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['ability:superadministrator,read-users|create-users']], function () {
    //..similar to the previous one
});
//some other route groups
```

The issue is, I can access the welcome page and also the login page. After authentication, I go to the home page and then the problem starts. Every other route than I try (like mydomain.net/law/search) leaves me to the home page again in some kind of infinity loop. The logout route also works fine.

Whats is strange to is that if I try a inexistent route like mydomain.net/blah, I go the the knowledge RouteNotFound/"NotFoundHttpException" of Laravel Framework.

I don't receive any error in php log or in my browser console. The javascript works fine.

I contact the support of the host service to ensure that Apache had the mod_rewrite enabled and apparently it is.

I googling for it about 3 hours and dig deeper here in SO, but anything helped me to understand the problem. Any tip?

Below is the .htacces file if it helps in any way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

MISC:

- PHP 7.1
- Laravel 5.4
- [The composer.json](https://pastebin.com/vm85Q4CH) for reference
- I'm using the [Laravel AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE) and the sidebar menu also does not work properly. I think that is the same problem causing the both issues.
- My .env file does not have anything special, but [here is (part of) it](https://pastebin.com/VZtSDrn6).

Comment: is mod_rewrite turned on?

Comment: According with the support guy, yes, but I can't ensure from my view of the system

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` before you deployed?

Comment: I made if after deploy. The "deploy" was a git clone in the hosting directory and and a `composer.phar install`. I followed the step-by-step of this [guide](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)

Comment: Sounds like maybe something to do with the middleware?  Eg authentication/session not working so those routes which require authentication are bouncing you away.  Are [directory permissions set correctly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This rule will internally load content of REQUEST_URI to the index.php