# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67 laravel 5.2 both are different

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I called Form::open its work and showing _token

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => URL::route('admin-login'), 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal m-t-20']) !!}

<form method="POST" action="http://example.net/admin/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal m-t-20"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="7ybw31c2ruMTjquv2lbyFAoIg1jBVySeQzBdrP">
```

session.php file

```
return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    //'lifetime' => 120,
    'lifetime' => 120*30*24*10,
    //'lifetime' => 360,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

I just dump the session token and form token value. both tokens are having different value

This session token changed on every refresh in server and remain same in localhost

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $sessionToken = $request->session()->token();

    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    var_dump($sessionToken);
    var_dump($token,true); die;

    if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
    }

    if (! is_string($sessionToken) || ! is_string($token)) {
        return false;
    }

    return hash_equals($sessionToken, $token);
}
```

RESULT OF VAR DUMP

```
var_dump($sessionToken);
EQ0oX12dMLLvI86MIb385vJ3e3U1DaIWiUVpt7Zx


var_dump($token,true); 
7ybw31c2ruMTjquv2lbyFAoIg1jBVySeQzBdrP
```

Following step I have tried but issue not solved

this issue happens in only server in and works fine in localhost

-Re-upload complete project from local to live

-Checked File Permission in Storage/Session directory (working fine and generating files)

-Cleared artisan cache

and also tried steps from [TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67)

**Solution from** 
[TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php](https://sdtuts.com/tokenmismatchexception-verifycsrftoken-php)

Solution: issue solved after restarting server.

Comment: config/session.php change secure => false then try

Comment: @Bugfixer its already false

Comment: if using https make SESSION_SECURE=true

Comment: @Bugfixer domain on http://