# TokenMisMatchException in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel and PHP. I am using POST method to get user requests and I am getting TokenMismatchException on in verifyCSRFToken.php line 68. Checked the logs in server.php found the following.

```
[2017-06-13 11:29:55] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Undefined constant 'home' in C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:762
```

Stack trace:

```
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(762): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...')
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Middle...')
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(72Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(138): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(576): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(535): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(513): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(14 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
C:\Users\Dikesh Kumar\blog\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\Users\\Dikesh...')
{main}
```

Could someone help?

Comment: have you added the csrf token in the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67)

Comment: Add the `{{ csrf_field }}` under your form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. Cross-site request forgeries are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of an authenticated user.

Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the csrf_field helper to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `csrf` token in your meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Or you can also pass as hidden input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If you are using `ajax` then you have to define `csrf` value as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
  </script>
```

and then run the following commnad:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying is that you know how to use the csrf token, however, after some time you get a token mismatch. This happens for example if your login page sits in your browser for a while where the form has generated the token already (as a hidden field). Now when you try to fill out the form, you are using the token that you generated (example: Yesterday) the last time you refreshed the page. On the back, once you submit the form, laravel will instantiate a new token and will compare against that token, which will be invalid.

You can change the session expiry inside `/app/config/session.php` from 120 minutes to anything longer than that.

Otherwise you can have an HTML meta refresh tag to refresh every 120 minutes so when the form is on idle, you can refresh the page and print the latest csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, this error can come from multiple sources. I didnt find my answer so i dig in laravel upgrade. I use database driver so i looked at the sessions table migration. Some of the new fields are nullable.
I fixed my table and it works.So if you have a problem with tokenmismatch, check if laravel can creates sessions(files or database).

Answer (score -1):

in `app/Http/helpers.php` you will find a space in the beginning of the file before `<?php` just remove it.