# Laravel: In which cases does the tokenmismatchexception come?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

The users of my Website told me that they got the tokenmismatchexception when the sent the formular.

If I try I didn't got it.

So, in which cases does the tokenmismatchexception come? How can I catch it?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866404/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67)

Comment: When session expires (user is logged out) you will get the `TokenMismatchException`. You can find settings for session in file `config/session.php` and the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#configuration).

Comment: To test that out, you can change the line `lifetime' => 120,` to `lifetime' => 1,` in `config/session.php`. Wait 1 for minute and try to submit the form.

Comment: and don't forget to turn it back to 120 when you are done testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears when:

- The user leaves the page opened for a long time of period, The default time is `2 hours` and can be configured in `config/session` - `lifetime`
- When you submit a form without including the `_token` field or without excluding the url on `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken`

To put the `_token` field on any form you can use `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

You can [check the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf) for more information